# My css blocks looks not adaptive with different size of resolution

Tags: html, css

I need to make 3 `div` blocks with height and width 200px and in the center of screen. And it should looks correctly with different resolutions.
It looks good on my laptop, but if I check with other resolutions, then one `div` is under other too. Sorry for my language, not native.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="koostooblock" style=" width:55%; margin:auto;">
        <div class="kt1" style="width:200px; height:200px; float:left; margin-right:1px; background:url(images/disaineritedele.png);"><p>Disaineritedele</p></div>
        <div class="kt2" style="width:200px; height:200px; float:left; margin-right:1px; background:url(images/ehitajatedele.png);"><p>Ehitajatedele</p></div>
        <div class="kt3" style="width:200px; height:200px; float:left; background:url(images/arhitekroritedele.png);"><p>Arhitekroritedele</p></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you want those divs to be responsive? if so you can't have fixed width

Comment: why dont u use width:33.33% something like this. here is one example:http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/MpXYr/2/

Comment: Typically fixed width elements are not very responsive. The stacking on smaller viewports happens because your elements are floated. When there isn't enough room for an element in a row of elements, the last one re-flows to the next line. In your case, as soon as the width of the viewport is less then `600px` the DIVs will start stacking vertically starting with the last one. You need to make a decision if the DIVs **have to be** `200px` wide. If so, then you need to accept that all three cannot be on the same row on smaller viewports.

Comment: @techLove - it is good but in mobile mode i need that div will be under another div

Comment: @DanielH - the same,  it is good but how to do that in mobile view div will be under another div? I think I need media queris may be but not skills how to use it

Answer (score 1):

Few things, try to use CSS style sheet as a better practice.

use `width: calc((100% - 2px)/3);` to get equal width for each width, 2px are the margin, since you have two margin assigned as 1px so thats 2px total.

### Updated using media queries for mobile screen size:

#### (Note: in CSS code order matters, so if you have media queries at top it won't work, keep in mind that)

```
/* mobile screen size */
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .kt1, .kt2, .kt3 {
    width: calc(100% - 1px);
  }
}
```

```css
.kt1 {
  width: calc((100% - 2px)/3);
  height: 200px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 1px;
  background: url(images/disaineritedele.png);
  background-color: yellow;
}

.kt2 {
  width: calc((100% - 2px)/3);
  height: 200px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 1px;
  background: url(images/ehitajatedele.png);
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

.kt3 {
  width: calc((100% - 2px)/3);
  height: 200px;
  float: left;
  background: url(images/arhitekroritedele.png);
  background-color: aqua;
}

.koostooblock {
  width: 55%;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: lightgray;
}

/* mobile screen size */
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .kt1, .kt2, .kt3 {
    width: calc(100% - 1px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="koostooblock">
  <div class="kt1">
    <p>Disaineritedele</p>
  </div>
  <div class="kt2">
    <p>Ehitajatedele</p>
  </div>
  <div class="kt3">
    <p>Arhitekroritedele</p>
  </div>
</div>
```